# Retrieve Array compressed by BlockCopy

Tags: c#, arrays, list, stream, buffer

I have two kinds of List: a list with int elements and other with bool elements. To pass these lists to server, I have to do what I did below:

```
using(MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream()){
  using(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(m)){
    byte[] bytesIntList = new byte[IntList.Count * sizeof(int)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(IntList.ToArray(), 0, bytesIntList, 0, bytesIntList.Length);
    writer.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(bytesIntList));

    byte[] bytesBoolList = new byte[BoolList.Count * sizeof(bool)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BoolList.ToArray(), 0, bytesBoolList, 0, bytesBoolList.Length);
    writer.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(bytesBoolList));
  }
  byte[] data = m.ToArray();
  return data;
}
```

Now, I'd like to know how do I do the reverse process: receive these lists:

```
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(data)){
  using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(m)){
    byte[] bytesIntList = Convert.FromBase64String(reader.ReadString());
    byte[] bytesBoolList = Convert.FromBase64String(reader.ReadString());
    List<int> newIntList = ??? //what do I have to do here?
    List<bool> newBoolList = ??? //what do I have to do here?
  }
}
```

If you have other suggestion to pass the Lists, it'll be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that although there is a way to easily go from an array of bytes to an array of ints, there *isn't* a way to go from an array of bytes to a list of ints.

You will have to convert it to an array first (like you did when saving it), or you will have to go through the byte buffer an int at a time.

Converting to an array first would look like this:

```
byte[] data = new byte[1000]; // Pretend this is your read-in data.

int[] result = new int[data.Length/sizeof(int)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, result, 0, data.Length);
List<int> list = result.ToList();
```

I think converting it an int at a time would be better though, since you won't need to convert it to an array first:

```
byte[] data = new byte[1000]; // Pretend this is your read-in data.
List<int> list = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < data.Length; ++i, j += sizeof(int))
    list.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(data, j));
```

And to convert a byte array to a bool array you can do this:

```
byte[] data = new byte[1000]; // Pretend this is your read-in data.
List<bool> list = new List<bool>();

for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < data.Length; ++i, j += sizeof(bool))
    list.Add(BitConverter.ToBoolean(data, j));
```

Alternatively, for converting bytes to bools we can use Linq (which is not so easy for converting bytes to ints):

```
byte[] data = new byte[1000]; // Pretend this is your read-in data.
List<bool> list = (from b in data select b != 0).ToList();
```

Or using a method instead of query syntax (if you prefer that):

```
byte[] data = new byte[1000]; // Pretend this is your read-in data.
List<bool> list = data.Select(b => b != 0).ToList();
```